# How to test the static_assert in my library with cmake?

Tags: c++11, cmake, automated-tests, static-assert

in my library code I have a bunch of static_asserts. I want to test if they fire under the expected conditions.

I would like to write a range of test files and

- ensure that they fail to compile
- check the output of the compilation attempt for the expected message from the static assert

Does anyone know how to do that with cmake?

AFAICT, try_compile is not the answer, because it is executed while running cmake. I need these checks to be executed during make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several more experiments, this is what I am doing now:

```
add_executable(
  fail_test
  EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL
  fail_test.cpp
  )

add_custom_command(OUTPUT fail_test.out
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM} fail_test > ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/fail_test.out 2>&1  || true
    COMMAND grep "int i = row.alpha" ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/fail_test.out > /dev/null
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/fail_test.cpp
    COMMENT "fail_test"
    )

add_custom_target(test_constraints DEPENDS fail_test.out COMMAND true)
```

This is what it does:

1. Create a target for compiling the code that is supposed to fail at compile time. Exclude this target from the default build so that it does not create a mess.
2. Add a custom command that calls `make` for this fail-target, pipes the compiler spew into a file, ignores the result code and then `grep`s for the expected compiler message that indicates that the compilation failed due to the expected reason.
3. Make the custom command depend on the source file, so that the compilation is tested again when the source file is ended.
4. Add the custom command as dependency to a custom target.

Of course, for more tests, steps 1, 2 and 4 would go into a function.

So now I can call

```
make test_constraints
```

to test if the stuff I want to fail compiling actually does so. And if something does not fail as expected, I can even call

```
make fail_test
```

to tune the test or its basis until it fails correctly.

For platform independence, the custom command will probably have to be adjusted. Suggestions welcome.

Comment: It's not a cross-platform solution, if you want to run this code on windows you need to redesign all from scratch

Comment: @ruslo That's what I wrote at the bottom of my text :-) I still think that it is the way to go, maybe using a python script instead of the current bash-commands.

Answer (score 2):

You could set up a "nested" project for these tests, configure it as part of your CMake run and then build it using `cmake --build`; something like this:

Your normal CMakeLists.txt:

```
# ...
execute_process(
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} path/to/test/project
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/TestProject
)

add_test(
  NAME StaticAsserts
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/TestProject
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .
)
# ...
```

Of course, the test command could actually be a wrapper script running `cmake --build` internally and processing its output.

As an alternative, you could move the configuration of the nested project into the test as well, perhaps using CTest to drive the configure & build.

Comment: Since compiling will fail for each and every source file in TestProject (I need that to fail), won't the `cmake --build` just bail out and let the StaticAsserts test fail?

Comment: @Rumburak You could process that in the wrapper script I mention; or simply do one `add_test()` per `static_assert()` and use test properties like `WILL_FAIL` and `PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION`.

Comment: I admit that I was hoping for a solution with less overhead, but this will certainly work :-)

Comment: After a few more weeks, I found the solution I was looking for. Less overhead, IMO, and no need to call ctest, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include(CTest)

# Test that code is NOT able to compile
function(TestStaticCheck TEST_NAME)
    add_executable(${TEST_NAME} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ${TEST_NAME}.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(${TEST_NAME} MyLibrary)
    add_test(NAME ${TEST_NAME}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target ${TEST_NAME}
        )
    set_tests_properties(${TEST_NAME} PROPERTIES WILL_FAIL TRUE)
endfunction()

TestStaticCheck(TestFoo)
```

Then put this in `TestFoo.cpp` in the same directory as your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
int main()
{
    // Code that should NOT compile
}
```